# How can i create graphical tools with command line interface?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, user-interface, command-line-interface

I am building a tool that can be both graphical or purely with a command line interface.
It's up to the user to decide with a command line option "--command_line_only". My IDE is Visual Studio 2008.

I can't seem to find the right project property to make sure

1. standard output prints are displayed when using the command line interface mode
2. no command line box is opened when using the tool in its graphical mode

Is there a way to do that ? Visual Studio's devenv seems to behave like this, so i am pretty sure it can be done !

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I seem to have answered your title, but on re reading your question I am not sure this is what you are asking.  I leave the answer here as it might be useful to someone searching your title

Yes you can do this but in general visual studies doesn't make it very easy to separate code from gui (particuly from the hello world examples that are very bound).  If you want to mix input then you really want to make sure this is done very well from the beginning.

My advice is to start with the command line options.  If you are allowed to use boost (for lisencing reasons) then use [boost::program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/program_options.html).

Then once you have got that going you can add the gui on top.  Also, I would recommonend using a gui library such as gtk++ as it is cross platform .

Answer (score 1):

Build the application as a Win32 application (not a console application), and examine the parameters to decide whether or not to use the console window.

The following code is [based on this](http://www.halcyon.com/~ast/dload/guicon.htm).

To use a console; create a class called CConsoleAttacher. Use it as follows, basically if there are arguments then open a console which will connect to the CMD window if you started from that. Obviously with Win32 applications when you launch the main windows it detaches from the console so this needs to be handled early on before creating app windows (which is what you want to do anyway...)

```
    CConsoleAttacher ca;
    if (ca.hasArguments())
    {
        ca.ConnectToConsole();
    }
    printf ("Test output \n");
```

Create a class called CConsoleAttacher.

## CConsoleAttacher.cpp

```
#include "StdAfx.h"

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "ConsoleAttacher.h"

#ifndef _USE_OLD_IOSTREAMS
using namespace std;
#endif
static const WORD MAX_CONSOLE_LINES = 500;

CConsoleAttacher::CConsoleAttacher(void)
{
    argv = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &argc);

}


CConsoleAttacher::~CConsoleAttacher(void)
{
    LocalFree(argv);
}


int CConsoleAttacher::getArgumentCount(void)
{
    return argc;
}


CString CConsoleAttacher::getArgument(int id)
{
    CString arg ;
    if (id < argc)
    {
        arg = argv[id];
    }
    return arg;
}

bool CConsoleAttacher::hasArguments(void)
{
    return argc > 1;
}

void CConsoleAttacher::ConnectToConsole(void)
{
    int hConHandle;
    HANDLE lStdHandle;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO coninfo;
    FILE *fp;

    // allocate a console for this app
    if (!AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS))
    {
        if (!AllocConsole())
            return;
    }

    // set the screen buffer to be big enough to let us scroll text
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),&coninfo);
    coninfo.dwSize.Y = MAX_CONSOLE_LINES;

    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),coninfo.dwSize);

    // redirect unbuffered STDOUT to the console
    lStdHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    hConHandle = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)lStdHandle, _O_TEXT);
    fp = _fdopen( hConHandle, "w" );

    *stdout = *fp;
    setvbuf( stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );

    // redirect unbuffered STDIN to the console
    lStdHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    hConHandle = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)lStdHandle, _O_TEXT);
    fp = _fdopen( hConHandle, "r" );

    *stdin = *fp;
    setvbuf( stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );

    // redirect unbuffered STDERR to the console
    lStdHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
    hConHandle = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)lStdHandle, _O_TEXT);
    fp = _fdopen( hConHandle, "w" );

    *stderr = *fp;
    setvbuf( stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );

    // make cout, wcout, cin, wcin, wcerr, cerr, wclog and clog
    // point to console as well
    ios::sync_with_stdio();
}
```

## CConsoleAttacher.h

```
#pragma once
class CConsoleAttacher
{
private:
    int argc;
    wchar_t** argv;

public:
    CConsoleAttacher(void);
    ~CConsoleAttacher(void);
    int getArgumentCount(void);
    CString CConsoleAttacher::getArgument(int id);
    void ConnectToConsole(void);
    bool hasArguments(void);
};
```

Comment: Your answer seems interesting, i have had to include <windows.h> but it does not seem to be enough. _O_TEXT is still undefined. What file should i include ?

Comment: I found correct files to include, but it does not work. When launching from cmd box, it creates a new one (probably prints things in there) then closes it.

Comment: This seems a bit odd. `HANDLE` can be 8 bytes wide, but you cast it to a 4 byte long. Are you sure?

Comment: I've rejigged the code to be more type friendly; however the *HANDLE* cast to *long* strangely works in x64, but the revisions use the right types.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an easy thing to do, IIRC. The problem is that on Windows the executable itself has a flag whether it is a GUI application or console application and e.g. `cmd.exe` behaves differently when executing one or the other. I suggest that you split the core functionality of your application into a library and build separate CLI and GUI front ends.

**EDIT**: If you really insist, this goes a long way towards the goal. The `goto` is there for historical reasons, it could be replaced by the `if` now:

```
static
bool
usable_handle (HANDLE h)
{
    return h && h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
}


static
bool
try_reopen_std_handle (int dest_handle, DWORD os_handle_num, HANDLE os_handle,
    int flags)
{
    if (! usable_handle (os_handle))
        return false;

    int ret = SetStdHandle (os_handle_num, os_handle);
    assert (ret);
    if (! ret)
        return false;

    int base_flags = 0;
#if defined (UNICODE)
    //base_flags = _O_WTEXT;
#endif

    int opened_handle = _open_osfhandle (reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(os_handle),
        flags | base_flags);
    assert (opened_handle != -1 && "_open_osfhandle");
    if (opened_handle == -1)
        return false;

    int dupd_handle = _dup2 (opened_handle, dest_handle);
    assert (dupd_handle != -1 && "_dup2");

    return dupd_handle == 0;
}


static
bool
try_fdopen (FILE * f, int handle, char const * mode)
{
    FILE * tmp = _fdopen (handle, mode);
    if (tmp && f)
        *f = *tmp;
    return !! tmp;
}


static
HANDLE
try_dup_os_handle (HANDLE src)
{
    if (! usable_handle (src))
        return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

    HANDLE dest = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    HANDLE const process = GetCurrentProcess ();
    if (DuplicateHandle (process, src, process, &dest, 0, TRUE,
        DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS))
        return dest;
    else
        return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
}


static
void
init_std_io ()
{
    // Retrieve inherited standard handles. AttachConsole() will close
    // the existing standard handles, so we duplicate them here first
    // to keep them alive.

    HANDLE os_stdin = try_dup_os_handle (GetStdHandle (STD_INPUT_HANDLE));
    HANDLE os_stdout = try_dup_os_handle (GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE));
    HANDLE os_stderr = try_dup_os_handle (GetStdHandle (STD_ERROR_HANDLE));

    // Attach existing console or allocate a new one.

    int ret = AttachConsole (ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);
    if (ret)
        OutputDebugString (_T("Attached existing console.\n"));
    else
    {
        ret = AllocConsole ();
        if (ret)
            OutputDebugString (_T("Allocated new console.\n"));
        else
            OutputDebugString (_T("Failed to allocate new console.\n"));
        assert (ret);
    }

    // Open a "POSIX" handle for each OS handle and then fdopen() a C stream
    // for each such "POSIX" handle.
    //
    // Only use the standard handle provided by AttachConsole() if the standard
    // handle from before AttachConsole() is not usable.
    //
    // Finally, re-open standard C stream.

    if (! usable_handle (os_stdin))
        os_stdin = GetStdHandle (STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    ret = try_reopen_std_handle (0, STD_INPUT_HANDLE, os_stdin, _O_RDONLY);
    if (! ret)
        goto do_stdout;
    try_fdopen (stdin, 0, "r");

do_stdout:
    if (! usable_handle (os_stdout))
        os_stdout = GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    ret = try_reopen_std_handle (1, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, os_stdout, _O_WRONLY);
    if (! ret)
        goto do_stderr;
    try_fdopen (stdout, 1, "w");

do_stderr:
    if (! usable_handle (os_stderr))
        os_stderr = GetStdHandle (STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
    ret = try_reopen_std_handle (2, STD_ERROR_HANDLE, os_stderr, _O_WRONLY);
    if (! ret)
        goto done_stderr;
    try_fdopen (stderr, 2, "w");

done_stderr:;
}
```

Comment: If i have to do that, it's pretty easy to do. I will simply compile two versions of my executable, the first one with flag console, the second one with flag windows ! But clearly i'd like to only have one. Hence my question.

Comment: @Benoît: IIRC, the problem is with the GUI marked executable. The cmd.exe will not wait for it to return.